# C++: Array with custom size in class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, opengl

I want to do this:

```
class Graphic
{
    int *array;
    Graphic( int size )
    {
        int temp_array[size];
        array = temp_array;
        glGenTextures( size, array );
    }
}
```

Will this work? And even if it will, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `new` means you have to remember to `delete []` it; using compiler-dependent variable-size arrays means you lose portability.

It's much better to **use a vector**.

```
#include <vector>

class Graphic
{
    std::vector<int> array;
    Graphic( int size )
    {
        array.resize(size);
        glGenTextures( size, &array[0] );
    }
}
```

The language guarantees that vector elements will be contiguous in memory so it's safe to do `&array[0]` here.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to use a `vector` with the `glGenTextures` function, but this makes sense. thanks!

Comment: @j_random_hacker I don't have upvote privileges yet, but I will accept the answer in a moment.

Comment: and now that I accepted your answer, I get upvote privileges. lol

Comment: @Jay: Works for me! :)  Actually that's interesting that new users can't upvote right away...  WTH can they do then? :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker we can ask and answer questions, but not comment anywhere except on our own questions... but just from asking a few questions, I have already gotten "comment anywhere" and "up vote" privileges.

Answer (score 1):

No, the memory for temp_array is allocated on the stack. When the function ends then that memory is deallocated and all you'll be left with is a dangling pointer. If you want to keep the array valid beyond the point that the constructor returns then allocate it dynamically using new. Example:

```
array = new int[size]
```

And then remember to delete it. Typically this is done in the destructor like this:

```
delete[] array
```

Comment: And then of course you're in trouble with copy and assignment. Much better to use a `std:vector`.

Comment: Better: use `std::vector` and the destructor is automatically generated for you (along with early exit due to exception, etc).  Also, the original code won't even compile, the C++ standard requires that `size` in `int temp_array[size];` must be a compile-time constant.

Comment: @Jay: You can still use `vector`.  The language guarantees that its elements will be contiguous in memory (for this exact reason), so you can take the address of the 1st element and pass it to `glGenTextures()`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yeah, I hadn't seen your answer yet.

Comment: @sje397: No, you're not in trouble because you can always implement those functions properly or deny that they are used. Whether std::vector is better or not is context dependent. Maybe the OP is ok with it deep copying the vector, or maybe he/she would rather it shared the pointer with another object. These are context dependent issues that become relevant when the class is used, but not in the answer to the question as it's posed.

Comment: @sashang: If you're going to remind the reader to delete the allocated memory, then why not remind them to handle it properly when copying or assigning? The latter is more complex and more likely to be an issue.